# Counter-intuitive results from kpss test (Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin), on perfectly linear series

Tags: time-series, stationarity, trend, kpss-test

I would assume that a perfectly linear time series would exhibit trend-stationarity. This is **not** what I find when I use run this test in both Python and R. The KPSS test for stationarity around a trend suggests that the perfectly linear relationship is not stationary.

Can someone please help me explain what I am missing?

## 1. Python

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import kpss

# Running the KPSS test on the generated time series
# Testing for stationarity around a trend (regression='ct')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': x, 'value': y})

kpss(df.value, regression='ct')

# Displaying the results
kpss_stat, p_value, critical_values

>>>
KPSS Statistic: 6.170364219353778
p-value: 0.01
critical_values: {'10%': 0.119, '5%': 0.146, '2.5%': 0.176, '1%': 0.216}
Result: **The series is not stationary**
```

## 2. In R, I get similar results

```
library(tseries)

# Create the time series
x <- seq(0, 99)
y <- 2 * x + 1
ts_data <- ts(y)

# Perform the KPSS test with null hypothesis of Trend stationarity
kpss_result <- kpss.test(ts_data, null = "Trend")

print(kpss_result)
KPSS Trend = 0.12592, Truncation lag parameter = 4, p-value = 0.08719
>>>Result: **The series is not stationary**
```

Comment: The KPSS test compares the random walk component to the residual noise component. Since they are both zero in this example, this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are you not contradicting yourself in the first sentence? You assume a trend-stationary series but conclude it is not stationary around the trend.

Comment: @RichardHardy The KPSS test output suggests that it is not stationary around the trend. But it quite clearly is (because 2 * x + 1 is perfectly linear, with no residual/variance). I've since, clarified the sentence, since this is confusing when we write we reject the null of stationarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas explains, this is likely just numerical instability - the residuals of such a regression will be essentially zero.

The KPSS statistic is

\begin{equation}\label{eq:eta}
\hat{\eta}:=(T^2\hat{\omega}_u^2)^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\left(\sum_{j=1}^t\hat{u}_j\right)^2,
\end{equation}
where the $\hat{u}_t$ are the residuals for, in the trend case, a regression of $y_t$ on a constant and a linear trend.

Also,
$$\hat{\omega}_u^2:=T^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\hat{u}_t^2+2T^{-1}\sum_{s=1}^lw(s,l)\sum_{t=s+1}^T\hat{u}_t\hat{u}_{t-s},$$
where $w$ is a kernel which fulfills, e.g., the conditions of Andrews (1991). The lag truncation parameter $l:=l_T$ depends on the sample size such that $\frac{1}{l}+\frac{l}{T}\to0$ for $T\to \infty$.
Under these conditions, $\hat{\omega}_u^2$ is a consistent estimator of $\omega_u^2$, the long-run variance.

Without autocorrelation in the errors one could simply use the standard estimator
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sigmahat}
\hat{\sigma}_u^2:=T^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^T\hat{u}_t^2
\end{equation}

Now, if the data also follows an exact linear trend, the regression will estimate that trend exactly, so that all residuals $\hat u_t$ are zero, and the test statistic $\hat \eta$ is not defined, as we would divide $0/0$.

That this is not what the code gives is due to numerical instability, in that the residuals are not estimated to be *exact* zeros.

Completing the OP's code with the additional lines of code below does not exactly give the printed statistic, as it does not employ a long run variance estimator but a standard variance estimator in the denominator but illustrates that both numerator and denominator of the KPSS statistic are essentially zero, leading to an errratic statistic:

```
trendreg <- lm(y~x)
sum(cumsum(resid(trendreg))^2)/(length(x)^2*var(resid(trendreg)))
summary(trendreg)
summary(resid(trendreg))
```

Comment: this outputs a value close to 0.09897527 which is still counter-intuitive (you would expect 0 or undefined for a series with zero variance). The Python implementation output a KPSS statistic of 6.17.

Comment: I did not claim that my code is any more intuitive, just that it maybe explains the numerical issue (which indeed is "unintuitive") - you can inspect `summary(trendreg)` or `summary(resid(trendreg))` to get some further ideas on how such small residuals may lead to instable results. (I cannot help with Python.)

Comment: I don't follow the math clearly so would appreciate a little bit of a more in-deph explanation. But are you saying that a perfectly linear series violates one of the assumptions of the test? It's interesting because the test statistic is undefined when testing for stationarity around a constant (unlike in the question). In this case, it asymptotically approaches zero. But for the case here where we input a perfectly linear relationship, the test outputs a real value which is counter-intuitive and more dangerous since unless I am mistaken it could easily get unnoticed, without visual inspection

Comment: Please refer to my edit for more detail. I think you understand quite well, no assumptions are violated, it's just numerical instability in my opinion. I also agree  that it would be good if the test gave a warning

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to deal with this, but I think it makes sense to implement the following changes to the test: 

a) when testing for stationarity around 0, check for zero variance in the time series: if so, cast/coerce KPSS to 0
b) when testing for stationarity around a trend, check if *both* the numerator [partial sums of the residuals] and denominator [number of observations x estimate of long-run variance] fall below a very small threshold: if so, cast/coerce KPSS to 0

If the numerator + denominator approach zero at different rates, this approach be a problem

Comment: I sent an email to the maintainer of `tseries` to suggest looking into this issue.

Comment: I wonder if a "regularization" method of simply adding a small number (e.g., 0.00001) to the denominator [number of observations x estimate of long-run variance] would solve the issue.

Comment: The maintainers of `tseries` have now included a warning. I would advise against such ad hoc additions - ultimately, the problem we have here is one of comparing variances from regressions, and if both of these are zero, it is just not a meaningful comparison. If the fit from a constant or trend regression is essentially perfect, the series does clearly not have a unit root.